# Angular active class on dynamic url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to add a class 'active' to my link:

```
<a href="#/requests/{{request.id}}/processes" active>Processes</a>
```

which outputs:

```
<a href="#/requests/7cgSiSdaIR/processes" active="">Processes</a>
```

This is my directive:

```
.directive('active', function($location) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      if('#'+$location.path() == attrs.href) {
        el.addClass('active');
      }
    }
  }
})
```

When I console.log(attrs.href) it outputs `#/requests//processes`, so the binding value is not there yet.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: do code in jsfiddle/plunker. it will help to detect an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.directive('active', function($location) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function(){
         return attrs.href;
      },function(newValue){
         el.toggleClass('active','#'+ $location.path() == newValue);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But I think you need this:

```
.directive('active', function($location) {
      return {
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(function(){
             return '#'+ $location.path() == attrs.href; //always update when one of them changes
          },function(newValue){
             el.toggleClass('active',newValue);
          });
        }
      }
 });
```